# Shifting database from one server to another

Tags: php, mysql

We are working on the CRM site. Now we have to shift the site from one server to another server. We are not having the problem for shifting the files since we are working on that so we know the changes or update in those files. But we have to shift the DB from one server to another server without losing a single data.We planned to make access the old server DB from the new server still we are changing the DB from old server to new server. But the problem is when we are doing this process the user have the possibilities to inserting the records to old DB. So we lose those data since we already taken the DUMP.So kindly suggest us what is the best way to doing the DB transfer with losing single data.

we are thinking to take the records between the times from dumping to changing to new server. Is that possible?.... if yes kindly suggest us how?...

Comment: Use [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/replication.html), e.g. as described in [Quick MySQL replication to move a database](http://blog.onetechnical.com/2012/05/29/quick-mysql-replication-to-move-a-database/).

Comment: Depending on the time it will take for you to process the migration, you could also just take the old server "down for maintenance" right before doing the dump.

Comment: @SajanParikh: Yes, because business critical applications should always be taken offline "for maintenance".  Google ought to take GMail and Google Search offline more often... they obviously don't maintain them enough!

Comment: @eggyal No need for the snark.  If the OP's application was that critical that it can't be taken down for 20 minutes to migrate the database, then it should already be replicated, clustered, or at the very least have a dedicated database server in which case this question would be pointless.

Comment: @SajanParikh: Okay, that's fair. My sarcasm was a little harsh and unjustified. Sorry :) but an offline migration could take considerably longer than 20 minutes.

Comment: @eggyal Not necessarily, depends on the machine I guess.  With a decent CPU and enough RAM, you can dump a 3GB DB in about 5 minutes, another 10 minutes to transfer, and another say 20 minutes to import and test.  Regardless, the "down for maintenance" option is is a solution, and one of the easier ones.  It's certainly not the best, but definitely a viable one considering the OP's goal was not to lose data.  Thanks.

Comment: If he's only developing / working on a CRM system its probably not mature and doesn't have much data he can pretty much just do an offline dump and copy with minimal down time.  to put this in perspective it takes me less than 2 minutes to dump move and restore a 2 gb dump from my internal CRM system here and thats not even using a powerful server (it was only 400 quid!)

Answer (score 0):

Allow updates from both servers, that is, the old DB server will take updates. When the DNS migration is finished, only then migrate the DB data. Still, there's likely to be some downtime, but scripts can speed this up.